# Sluggish response from custom slider

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, uislider

I am trying to create a custom slider that uses a `UIButton` as the thumb.  Since I can't seem to find a way to use a `UIView` as the thumb in a slider, I decided to build a custom one.  However, when I run it, the thumb is sluggish to respond on the initial drag.  The following is the code so far.  The gif below is running slower than actual speed but illustrates the point.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomSlider: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    let buttonView = UIButton()
    var minimumPosition = CGPoint()
    var maximumPosition = CGPoint()
    var originalCenter = CGPoint()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        // add a pan recognizer
        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(recognizer:)))
        recognizer.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        buttonView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.height, height: bounds.height)
        buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        self.addSubview(buttonView)

        minimumPosition = CGPoint(x:buttonView.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
        maximumPosition = CGPoint(x: bounds.width - buttonView.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
    }

    @objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            originalCenter = buttonView.center
        }
        if recognizer.state == .changed {
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
            let newX = originalCenter.x + translation.x
            buttonView.center = CGPoint(x: min(maximumPosition.x, max(minimumPosition.x, newX)), y: buttonView.frame.midY)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: sluggish_thumb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  It only happens in the iPhone XR simulator.  Tried the iPhone XS, among others, and they were smooth as glass.

Answer (score 0):

To make it look smoother, you should reset the translation of the pan and just add it continuously to the center offset:

```
@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        // originalCenter = buttonView.center
    }
    if recognizer.state == .changed {
        originalCenter = buttonView.center
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
        let newX = originalCenter.x + translation.x
        buttonView.center = CGPoint(x: min(maximumPosition.x, max(minimumPosition.x, newX)), y: buttonView.frame.midY)

        recognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)
    }
}
```

Also, for making a custom control, you can check out this tutorial:
https://www.sitepoint.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/

It might be old and in objective-c, but it gives the general idea of overriding UIControl, handling touches and creating a custom control - which you can also extend with @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also found an updated tutorial on Ray Wenderlich [https://www.raywenderlich.com/7595-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider].  I worked through the example and just after adding the touch handlers, had the same problem.  I them went to the storyboard, dragged in a stock UISlider and saw the same issue.  Looks like it may be an iOS Simulator problem, not an issue with my code.  I did move the `originalCenter` line like you recommended to make things cleaner.  Thanks for your help.